# How to prevent showing loading spinner when a link is clicked on a page in android webview app?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, webview

I am working on a page loading spinner for a website, it is working fine in desktop and mobile browsers but an issue occurs when website is loaded in android mobile webview app.

When I click Facebook link on my website loaded in android mobile webview app it opens Facebook website in mobile browser, but when I switch back to android webview app I found previous page is loaded and it is also showing loading spinner continuously that disappears when I refresh the page.

I will prefer JavaScript/jQuery solution.

**Html**

```
<div class="loading-spinner-fixed">
     <div class="spinner"></div>
</div>

<a href="https://www.facebook.com/pagename" target="_blank">Facebook</a>
```

**CSS**

```
.loading-spinner-fixed {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    margin: -30px 0 0 -30px;
    z-index: 99999999;
    box-shadow: 0 0 12px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}


.loading-spinner-fixed .spinner {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    display: table-cell;
    margin: -16px 0 0 -16px;
    border: 4px solid #f3f3f3;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-top: 4px solid #00bbcc;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    animation: spin .5s linear infinite;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.loading-spinner-fixed').hide();
});

$(window).on('beforeunload', function () {
    $('.loading-spinner-fixed').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your activity override `onResume()` lifecycle method and add this line

```
if(mWebView != null){
   mWebView.load("javascript:$('.loading-spinner-fixed').hide();")
}
```

This will call hide to your `.loading-spinner-fixed` class